# Given that $f \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ and the sequence of Fourier coefficients $(\hat{f_n})\in l^1(\mathbb{Z})$, must $f$ be continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series, lp-spaces

Note that $\mathbb{T} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1 \}$. This detail wouldn't fit in the title.

This is a previous exam question I am practicing with and I'm at a loss! Any advice on how to think about this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is $\hat{f}_n$?

Comment: Ah, sorry for the ambiguity. It's the sequence of Fourier coefficients of $f$. I'll edit the title to reflect that.

Comment: $f = \sum_n \langle f,e_n \rangle e_n$ in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$. If $\sum_n |\langle f,e_n \rangle| < \infty$ then $\sum_n \langle f,e_n \rangle e_n$ converges uniformly thus is continuous and $f$ is equal to a continuous function almost everywhere and in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$

Comment: What is so special about $\mathbb{T}$ here? Its compactness? I don't get it. Also, the notation is confusing. $\mathbb{T}$ usually denotes a torus but here it denotes the unit circle if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @stressedout in the context of complex analysis it is standard to denote the unit circle by $\mathbb{T}$.

Comment: @reuns Is that the best that can be said about this? how do you know that $f$ can't be in $C(\mathbb{T})$? (the set of continuous functions on $\mathbb{T}$)? Do you have a counter-example? Thanks.

Comment: @reuns i agree with what you've written, but I'm not seeing how the fourier coefficients figure in. Is it the $\sum_n | \langle f, e_n \rangle | < \infty$ assumption?

Comment: Sure $(e_n)$ is the orthonormal basis of complex exponentials, $\langle .,. \rangle$ is the inner product and $\langle f,e_n \rangle = \hat{f}(n)$ (or $\hat{f}(n)/\sqrt{2\pi}$ depending on your normalization)

Comment: @stressedout I was re-reading my old Fourier Analysis textbook and I remember better now so as to clear up your confusion. The unit circle *is* the 1-dimensional torus, which justifies the notation $\mathbb{T}$. Also, we use the torus because functions on the torus are analogous to $2\pi$-periodic functions on $\mathbb{R}$, and these are apparently of great interest in Fourier analysis.

Comment: @BenW Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\in L^2$, then $\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\hat{f}(n)e^{inx}$ converges to $f$ in $L^2$. Assuming that $\hat{f} \in \ell^1$, then the series also converges absolutely and uniformly, which means that $f$ is equal a.e. to a continuous function.

Comment: Why does the fact that $\sum_{n=-N}^N \hat{f}(n) e^{inx}$ converges to $f$ in $L^2$ and uniformly imply that $f$ is continuous a.e.?

Comment: Actually, I take it back. It's because $\sum_{n=-N}^N \hat{f}(n) e^{inx}$ is continuous and the uniform limit of a continuous function is continuous.